# How can I do a bulk refactor in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, refactoring, dynamics-crm-2011

We are in the process of converting from Dynamics CRM 4.0 to Dynamics CRM 2011.  We have 100kloc+ written against auto-generated proxy classes (outputed by the crmsvcutil.exe program).

The new version of this utility changes the naming of proxy classes so this:

```
    var myEntity = new MyEntity();
    myEntity.MyField = 2;
```

Is now this:

```
    var myEntity = new new_myentity();
    myEntity.new_myfield = 2;
```

I can automate the matching of symbols so that I know the `MyEntity` is `new_myentity`, but now I need a way to update my code with all of the new symbols.

Comment: Do you use `ReSharper`? Can you use `Visual Studio` rename refactoring?

Comment: you can use regex find/replace from within visual studio.

Comment: Both VS and ReSharper can do one at a time, we are talking hundreds of symbols that need to be updated.

Comment: Sounds like job security then.

Comment: Based on your question, it sounds like your data model has changed (the table name MyEntity is now new_myentity).  Its not the utility that has changed, but your table names and field names.